# Show the date according to it's created timezone - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Suppose there's an event created in country A,
and the timeString is `"2015-08-27T16:00:32+02:00"`
A person (me) wants to see the event's time but not according to my local gmt, lets say mine is `+05:00`.. I want to show the user the creator's timezone i.e.

```
2015-08-27T16:00:32+02:00
```

In short, the time shown should be `4:00PM (according to +02:00)` , not `7:00PM (according to +05:00)`

is there any solution using the native javascript Date object or moment.js?

Comment: Perhaps you should use time in UTC. And adding the time zone depending on the user. Be careful with DTS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590429/calculating-daylight-savings-time-from-only-date

Comment: Yes I am actually worried about the DTS.. Is there any alternative that I could use perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You should save in your database the date and the timezone of the creator. Then when you have to display them, you can do something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    moment.tz.add('America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0');
    
    var date = moment('2015-08-27T16:00:32+02:00'); // Get date from db
    $('#date').html(date.format('LLLL')); // Display date using the browser's timezone
    var timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';// Get timezone from db
    $('#newDate').html(date.clone().tz(timezone).format('LLLL')); // Clone the date, set the new timezone and display
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.4.0/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id="date"></pre>
<pre id="newDate"></pre>
```

In this example, you get the date from the database and you display it in the upper box. As always, moment tries to use your browser's timezone to display the date.

Then you get the timezone from the database, you set the new timezone and you can see that the dates changes in the lower box.

Obviously this example **works only if you are not in the `America/Los_Angeles` timezone**. In this case you should get two equal strings, which is actually the correct behavior but it wouldn't allow you to see moment_timezone in action.